# Jekyll - Auto-regeneration not working even with watch used

Tags: ruby, jekyll

When running any of these commands:

```
jekyll serve
bundle exec jekyll serve
bundle exec jekyll serve --watch
bundle exec jekyll serve --force_polling
```

I get:

> Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.

and I can't see local updates until I stop (ctrl+c) and run the command again!

jekyll version (`jekyll -v`) gives `jekyll 3.4.3` which is the same as in my `gemfile`

What should I do to enable watching changes?

Comment: Are you using `jekyll-admin` plugin?

Comment: @ashmaroli, yes I installed it, does it cause problems?

Comment: yes, if you're using `v0.4.1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plugin `jekyll-admin` `v0.4.1` disables `--watch` internally. There are three ways to proceed:

- Remove the plugin if you're editing template files.
- Edit your Markdown files through the Admin interface
- Use an older version of the plugin

Comment: Great! I just disabled it and watching is working again! Thank you.